# How to import python 3.7 into Processing

Tags: python, processing

I think I’m using python 2 for my current Processing app on my Mac.
I have been trying to import python 3.7 but I couldn’t find out how to do it.
I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me. Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this thread](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/17202/python-3), the Python mode in Processing is based on [Jython](https://www.jython.org/), which is Python 2 syntax only.

So, unfortunately, Python 3 in Processing is probably impossible.